# how to open web browser in unix box?

Tags: linux, unix, url, webbrowser-control, twebbrowser

https://vitux.com/four-web-browsers-for-the-linux-command-line/
$ sudo apt-get install w3m w3m-img

i have an url generated in my unix machine and i wanna open that in web browser for which i am facing this problem.

i have tried installing these but i get this error "X Application is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

The w3m Tool 
The Lynx Tool 
The Links2 Tool 
The Elinks Tool

Comment: You should specify environment and command that you are trying execute.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your sudo command is broken. Not good. It's fixable.

https://www.tecmint.com/fix-user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-the-incident-will-be-reported-ubuntu/